# Induced connections

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles, connections

Let $E\rightarrow M$ be a be a vector bundle. From this bundle, we can construct various other bundles such as $E^*$, and $E\otimes E$. I know that if we have a connection, or covariant derivative $\nabla:\Gamma(E)\rightarrow \Omega^1(M,E)$, then there are induced connection on these bundles given by:

$$(\nabla^*\Xi)(\Phi)=\nabla(\Xi(\Phi))-\Xi(\nabla\Phi)$$
$$\nabla^\otimes(\Phi\otimes \Psi)=\nabla\Phi\otimes \Psi+\Phi\otimes\nabla\Psi$$

where $\Xi\in\Gamma(E^*)$, and $\Phi,\Psi\in \Gamma(E)$.

My question is then this, I can show that these are indeed connections on the aforementioned vector bundles, but is there a reason, other than verifying some version of the product rule, that these should be the induced connections on the vector bundles $E^*$ and $E\otimes E$? In other words, are these connections somehow uniquely/naturally/canonically determined given $\nabla$? It seems these definitions are pulled out of thin air, while, for example, the definition of the Lie derivative naturally extends to deducing relations such as the ones above.

Comment: The systematic way of treating all of these constructions is using principal bundles. A principal bundle is essentially just the data of the transition functions you use to define a vector bundle. In particular from a vector bundle $E$ you can construct its frame bundle, which is such a principal bundle. There is a notion of connection on principal bundles, which will be equivalent to the definition using covariant derivatives.

Comment: @CarlosEsparza I know the construction of a connection on a vector bundle associated to a principal bundle's (and we can go the other way by constructing a frame bundle for a vector bundle $E$), but I still don't see how that tell's me that these induced connections are the natural choices.

Comment: A connection on the principal bundle will induce a connection on the vector bundle. If you start with a vector bundle $E$, you can build its frame bundle $P := \mathrm{Fr}(E)$ and a covariant derivative $\nabla$ on $E$ will correspond to a connection $\omega$ on $P$. If you recover $E$ from $P$ by using the "standard" representation $\rho$ of $GL(n, \mathbb{R})$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$, the connection you get on $E = P \times_\rho \mathbb{R}^n$ will be $\nabla$.

Comment: If you use the representation $σ$ of $GL(n, \mathbb{R})$ on $\mathbb{R}^n ⊗ \mathbb{R}^n$ you will get the natural connection on $E ⊗ E = P \times_σ (\mathbb{R}^n ⊗ \mathbb{R}^n)$, the representation of $GL(n, \mathbb{R})$ on ${\mathbb{R}^n}^*$ gives you $E^*$ with the natural connection etc.

Comment: Hmm I think I see. So the properties actually follow form the induced representation of the Lie algebra on a the tensor product and dual space?

Comment: What properties do you mean?

Comment: Sorry I meant the defining properties of the induced connections, perhaps I worded that incorrectly

Comment: Oh I see what you meant. Yes, that is exactly what happens.

Comment: Perhaps this is dumb, but I guess my question is then why is it that $E\otimes E=P\times _\sigma(\mathbb{R}^n\otimes \mathbb{R}^n)$, and not $E\otimes E=Q\times _{\rho}(\mathbb{R}^n\otimes \mathbb{R}^n$ where $Q$ is the bundle of frames form for $E\otimes E$, or I guess $Q=P$, since a frame for $E$ induces a frame for $E\otimes E$?

Comment: Both of those are ways you can induce $E ⊗ E$ from a principal bundle. But you don't have $Q = P$, rather there is a bundle map $P \to Q$ corresponding to the natural homomorphism $GL(V) \to GL(V ⊗ V)$. One way to think of this is that every frame for $E$ gives you a frame for $E ⊗ E$ but not vice versa.

Comment: Since $\nabla$ is supposed to play the role of a derivative and $\otimes$ is multiplication, you shouldn’t be so surprised that product rule comes in. In fact, product rule plus “commutes with contraction” characterizes all the induced connections.

Comment: @Mr.Brown I’m not surprised that it comes up, it makes sense. I just wanted an argument to see that this is actually the natural choice of an induced connection

Comment: My point is that it is a natural choice once we accept the two things I said above as fundamental (and I guess the fact that covariant derivatives should act as normal derivatives on functions).

Comment: For example, in the following computation I use only the three things listed above. $$0=X(dx^i(\partial_j))=\nabla_X(dx^i(\partial_j))=\nabla_X(dx^i)\partial_j+dx^i\nabla_X \partial_j,$$
which gives your definition of $\nabla_X dx^i$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The induced connections become natural to understand by considering the parallel transport maps.

The operation of taking the dual or the tensor product of vector spaces are functors, so for the parallel transport maps there are natural induced maps on the dual spaces and tensor products:

For a smooth curve $\gamma:I\to M$ and $t_0,t_1\in I$  let

$$
P^\nabla:E_{\gamma(t_0)}\to E_{\gamma(t_1)}
$$

be the parallel transport along $\gamma$ corresponding to $\nabla$. Then the parallel transport maps corresponding to $\nabla^\otimes$ and $\nabla^*$ are given by

$$
{(P^\nabla})^*:{E^*}_{\gamma(t_1)}\to {E^*}_{\gamma(t_0)},\;\;{(P^\nabla})^*(\varphi)(v)=\varphi({P^\nabla}(v))$$

$$P^\nabla\otimes P^\nabla:E_{\gamma(t_0)}\otimes E_{\gamma(t_0)}\to E_{\gamma(t_1)}\otimes E_{\gamma(t_1)},\;\;P^\nabla\otimes P^\nabla(u\otimes v)= P^\nabla(u)\otimes P^\nabla(v)
$$
Since the connections can be recovered from the parallel transport maps $\nabla^*$  and $\nabla^\otimes$  are the unique connections with these properties.

Comment: Interesting, where can I find a source that goes into more detail? Specifically on the category theory applied to connections part?

Comment: Im not aware of such a source. I would also be interested. If you want to verify that these are indeed the induced parallel transport maps you can take a parallel frame $(e_1,\ldots e_n)$ along $\gamma$. Then from the product rule it follows that $\nabla^\otimes e_i\otimes e_j=0$. The dual frame $(e^1,\ldots,e^n)$ is calulated to be parallel with respect to $\nabla^*$ and in general if a linear isomorphism is given by $v_i\mapsto w_i$ on a basis the dual map is given by $w^i\mapsto v ^i$.

Comment: I believe it, I just get a little excited when I see category theory where I havent before